# Chart displaying values outside the min and max ranges (Chart.js)

Tags: javascript, chart.js

When I set a min and max value for my chart it still displays all the MIN values squished up to the left of my graph, but the max values disappear as they should.

HTML

```
<div id="graph">
<canvas id="line-chart" width="400" height="225"></canvas>          
</div>
<button id="12hours">12 Hours</button>
<button id="24hours">24 Hours</button>
```

JS

```
function displayGraph(object) 
{

timestamp = getDataForGraph(object, 'timestamp');
temp1 = getDataForGraph(object, 'temp1');
temp2 = getDataForGraph(object, 'temp2');
temp3 = getDataForGraph(object, 'temp3');

var mychart = new Chart(document.getElementById("line-chart"), {
    type: 'line',

    data: {
        labels: timestamp,
        datasets: [{
                data: temp1,
                label: "Temp 1",
                borderColor: "#ff0000",
                fill: false
            }, {
                data: temp2,
                label: "Temp 2",
                borderColor: "#3bff00",
                fill: false
            }, {
                data: temp3,
                label: "Temp 3",
                borderColor: "#00edff",
                fill: false
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        fontSize: 5
                    },
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        unit: 'hour',
                        displayFormats: {
                            hour: 'HH:mm:ss'
                        }
                    }
                }],
            yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        fontSize: 5
                    }
                }]
        }

    }
});

$('#12hours').off().on('click', function () {
    mychart.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.min = '2018-10-29 08:00:00';
    mychart.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.max = '2018-10-29 20:00:00';
    mychart.update();
});

$('#24hours').off().on('click', function () {
    mychart.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.min = '2018-10-29 00:00:00';
    mychart.options.scales.xAxes[0].time.max = '2018-10-29 23:59:59';
    mychart.update();
});
}
```

Current output when using min and max values. 
would like to get rid of all the values before 08:00 that are showing up on the left hand side of the axes.

[What it looks like when max and min are placed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxSvn.png)

[What it looks like with no max or min placed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnJ1U.png)